# PGmc strong class 4 verb

Tags: proto-germanic

Why is PGmc *brekaną strong class **4** verb (not class **5**)?
It doesn't have the ablaut vowel followed by a sonorant (m, n, l, r).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably for the same reason that similarly structured roots can also be found in class 3: metathesis.

[The Wikipedia article on strong Germanic verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb#Classes_1_to_6) notes:

> In class 3, there are also a few cases where the vowel is followed, at least in Proto-Germanic, by two consonants, neither of which is a nasal or a liquid.[3] Examples: **brestaną* "to burst", **þreskaną* "to thresh" **fehtaną* "to fight". All but one have a nasal or a liquid *in front* of the vowel. This will have become syllabic and resulted regularly in *u* before the nasal or liquid, which was then metathesised on the analogy of the remaining principle parts. E.g. part 3 of **brestaną* will have been **bʰr̥st-* > **burst-*, reformed to **brust-*.
>
> <sup>[Note 3] Ringe, Don. 2006. *A Linguistic History of English. From Proto-Indo-European to Proto-Germanic*, pp. 226, 243.</sup>

The same applies in class 4: the zero-grade of Proto-Indo-European **bʰreg-* was **bʰr̥g-*, which by regular sound change would, and probably did, yield Proto-Germanic **burk-*. But since the three other principal forms of the verb all (regularly) retained **brVk* in PG (**brek-*, **brok-*, **brēk-*), the fourth one – which appeared only in the past participle – was reworked to **bruk-* as well, to match the others.